# Magento how to Shopping Cart Price Rule exclude special price products？

Tags: magento

I have created the rule, but when multiple products together,  special price products also discounted！

**Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products)**

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true:

Special Price  less than  0.01
Special Price To Date  equals or less than  2015-04-29

**Apply :Percent of product price discount**

**Discount Amount :8**

**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)**

If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :

Special Price  less than  0.01
Special Price To Date  equals or less than  2015-04-29

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. Is this question about programming? If not, you should remove it and post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Special Price less than 0.01`, try `Special Price does not contain 0`.

Comment: thanks,'Special Price does not contain .'is wok,But when there is general product and special price product  together  ‘Special Price To Date equals or less ’ does not work !

Answer (score 0):

Need filter by **Special price**

But filter will applied for all products with value of special_price.

Strange, but Date range for special price, not works in Rule.

Need update product data

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104811/9951